# Able to generate documentation using mvn site command without using mvn-site-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am able to generate project documentation using using `mvn site` command without specifying `mvn-site-plugin` in my pom, which confuses me.

Does mvn already has this plugin installed by default? If yes, in which scenario should I use this plugin? What advantage does it serve?

Comment: You can also execute `mvn clean` and `mvn install` w/o specifying plugins, can't you? Read this - http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html.

Comment: Yes, i agree. So, if i put this plugin `mvn-site-plugin` in my pom what advantage does it offer? What all functionality/features does it bring?